# MySQL is hiding my Routines (stored procedures)

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

After creating a couple of Routines in MySQL, I came back to my database and they were missing, but still showing the name.

[image: phpMyAdmin Screenshot]

It says that I *might* be lacking the privileges necessary to edit them, but that is not the case.  I am logged in with the same account that created them, which is an admin account.

To see if they were in the information_schema, I ran this:

`SELECT routine_definition
FROM information_schema.routines
WHERE routine_schema = 'databasename';`

...but it shows two null entries.

[image: phpMyAdmin screenshot]

Are my Routines completely gone?  Did I do something wrong when creating them?

I've used MySQL for years and haven't had this happen before.

EDIT:
I just called the Routines and they do work... meaning they return the data.  My only issue is that I cannot view or edit the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Motion Hosting responded with an explanation.

> Unfortunately due to the recent changes by cPanel, use of MySQL routine is not something that is officially supported on a shared hosting plan. While it may be possible to manually create it through a custom phpMyAdmin install via your cPanel credential, the interface provided by cPanel will no longer work to modify routines. If you need support for routines, you will need to upgrade to a VPS or higher plan.

From what I understand, MySQL sets the security of the routine to "DEFINER" which identifies you by your login.  Once you log out and back in, that ID has changed, thereby hiding your routine code.

Similarly, the routines do not show up in a MySQL backup, either.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on which hosting service you are using. Although I have researched several times on Google, I have not found any solution that works for me.

As soon as I log in with cpanel -> phpmyadmin I am unable to run routines.

[I am unable to edit and export routines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7R2Nr.png)

**Solution :**

1. Log in as the root user of whm
2. From the left menu bar, search for phpmyadmin [Access to PHPMyAdmin's root account](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q8y1q.png)
3. Routines will be accessible to you [routine access](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HsExJ.png)